# Limit​ without L'hopital or series

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$.

I thought of designing a function and using sandwich theorem but couldn't find anything

Edit

Is there any algebric way to solve the limit? For example we can solve the limit

(Sinx-x)/x   x tending to 0 by replacing x by 3y where y tends to 0

Comment: This is the definitionf of the derivative of $x\longmapsto e^x$ at $0$, and $e^x$ is defined as the unique solution of $y'=y$ with $y(0)=1$. So it's totally equivalent to l'hopital... how can you do without ?

Comment: @Surb Your comment delineates a proof **without L'H**. "So it is **not** equivalent to L'H"...

Comment: Please let me know why is this put on hold as off topic

Comment: The answer to your question crucially depends on definition of symbol $e^{x} $ which is the missing context here. This is probably one of the reasons for closure. Please include your definition as well as your own efforts to solve this problem.

Comment: e can be defined as 1+1/1!+1/2!.....

Comment: "Please let me know why is this put on hold as off topic" Probably because you put zero personal input in it. The remark applies to quite a few of your recent questions, already closed or not, and delineates an improper approach to the site, viewed as a free answering service.

Comment: @Did  I don't believe that's true

Comment: You asked for a reason, I gave you the most probable one, the rest does not concern me. All I can say is that this denial comment of yours does not bode well for your future relation to the site but, again, this is not my problem.

Comment: This was all I could think. I didn't know how to start. If I'm not getting ideas it's not my fault. I'm a beginner and at least I'm trying hard to learn something

Answer (score 1):

This is just the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$ and therefore the limit is $1$.

Comment: Isn't that using L'Hopital?

Comment: No, it is the **definition** of the derivative.

Comment: Fair! Sorry I didn't notice that. You have to admit it looks exactly like L'Hopital though!

Comment: Of course it looks like! L'Hospital is equivalent to Taylor's formula at order $1$, which  itself is equivalent to the existence of a derivative.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable, then the $0/0$ form of LHR may be proven by noting $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-a}}=\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$LHR generalizes this and removes the need for continuity of the derivatives.

Comment: @MarkViola: Would you count this answer as LHT or would you accept it as an answer to the OPs’ question?

Comment: It's not LHR; it's the definition of the derivative.

Comment: In this case one has to ask why the derivative of $e^{x} $ at $x=0$ is $1$. Such questions can't be answered unless a proper definition of symbol $e^{x} $ is available.